# Anonymous Type Variable with Explicit Casting

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

Can you declare an anonymously-typed variable with explicit casting?

For example, you can do this:

```
var student = new { ID = 1 , name = "Jim" };
```

But not this:

```
var student = new { int ID = 1 , string name = "Jim" };
```

The goal is to have a variable that is:

- read-only
- has multiple explicitly-typed properties with default values
- can be declared within a method for temporary usage

As for the question of 'Why?', this is more of an informational curiosity of mine. Suppose you wanted `ID` to be an `Int64`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, anonymous types determine the data type implicitly.

> Suppose you wanted ID to be an Int64.

Then be explicit by [casting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) to the type you require:

```
var student = new { ID = (long)1 , name = "Jim" };
```

or by using a [suffix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
var student = new { ID = 1L , name = "Jim" };
```

Comment: Just for reference, [here is the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx) about doing `1L` to get a `long`

Comment: Thanks @ScottChamberlain - I was searching for exactly that as you commented.